# Count combinations of length 2 per id

Tags: r, data.table

I have a largish `data.table` with two columns, `id` and `var`:

```
head(DT)
#    id var
# 1:  1   B
# 2:  1   C
# 3:  1   A
# 4:  1   C
# 5:  2   B
# 6:  2   C
```

I would like to create a kind of cross-table that would show how many times different length 2-combinations of `var` occured in the data.

**Expected output** for the sample data:

```
out
#    A  B C
# A  0  3 3
# B NA  1 3
# C NA NA 0
```

**Explanation:**

- the diagonal of the resulting matrix/data.frame/data.table counts how many times all `var`s that occured for an `id` were all the same (either all `A`, or `B`, or `C`). In the sample data, `id` 4 only has one entry and that is `B`, so `B` - `B` is 1 in the desired result.
- the upper triangle counts for how many `id`s two specific `var`s were present, i.e. the combination `A` - `B` is present in 3 `id`s, as are combinations `A` - `C` and `B` - `C`.
- Note that for any `id`, a single combination of two `var`s can only be either 0 (not present) or 1 (present), i.e. I don't want to count it multiple times per `id`.
- the lower triangle of the result can be left NA, or 0, or it could have the same values as the upper triangle, but that would be redundant.

(The result could also be given in long-format as long as the relevant information is present.)

I'm sure there's a clever (efficient) way of computing this, but I can't currently wrap my head around it.

**Sample data:**

```
DT <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), var = c("B", "C", "A", 
"C", "B", "C", "C", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "C", 
"B", "A", "C", "B")), .Names = c("id", "var"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")

library(data.table)
setDT(DT, key = "id")
```

Comment: How large is largish?

Comment: @Heroka a few million rows at the moment, let's say 3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you're ok with long-form results:

```
DT[, if(all(var == var[1]))
       .(var[1], var[1])
     else
       as.data.table(t(combn(sort(unique(var)), 2))), by = id][
   , .N, by = .(V1, V2)]
#   V1 V2 N
#1:  A  B 3
#2:  A  C 3
#3:  B  C 3
#4:  B  B 1
```

Or if we call the above output `res`:

```
dcast(res[CJ(c(V1,V2), c(V1,V2), unique = T), on = c('V1', 'V2')][
          V1 == V2 & is.na(N), N := 0], V1 ~ V2)
#   V1  A  B C
#1:  A  0  3 3
#2:  B NA  1 3
#3:  C NA NA 0
```

---

An alternative to `combn` is doing:

```
DT[, if (all(var == var[1]))
       .(var[1], var[1])
     else
       CJ(var, var, unique = T)[V1 < V2], by = id][
   , .N, by = .(V1, V2)]
#    V1 V2 N
# 1:  A  B 3
# 2:  A  C 3
# 3:  B  C 3
# 4:  B  B 1

# or combn with list output (instead of matrix)

unique(DT, by=NULL)[ order(var), if(.N==1L)
       .(var, var)
     else
       transpose(combn(var, 2, simplify=FALSE)), by = id][
   , .N, by = .(V1, V2)]
```

Comment: Nice! I was thinking along these lines. However, in the case of multiple identical vars (like only 'B' s for id 5, but four of them), you would get an n < m error from `combn` I think.

Comment: Thanks eddi! I'll have to investigate that a bit (+1)

Comment: Nice, that transpose is going to be rough though, can't you just set simplify = FALSE on combn and work with the list?

Comment: @Shape I haven't checked speeds, but I guess smth along these lines could work: `rbindlist(lapply(combn(v, 2, simplify = F, FUN = as.list), setDT))`

Comment: @eddi, can you show in your answer how that `rbindlist(...)` from the comment would fit into the rest of your answer?

Comment: should just replace the `as.data.table(...)` part after the else

Comment: @docendodiscimus it would replace `as.data.table(t(combn(...)))`, but I don't think it's worth it, I just ran a quick speed test and simple `t` is way faster

Comment: depends how variable the number of variables is, I think you might see a difference if the number of vars get large

Comment: @Shape, the number of vars-combinations is relatively low compared to the number of `id`s (could be in the range 100-200)

Comment: I added a different version that avoids `combn` altogether, hopefully alleviating the above concerns

Comment: Maybe I'm just wrong, I'm testing this,I remember t being much more painful, but t just destroys the competition here... wow

Comment: This is awesome, eddi - thank you so much! It only takes a few seconds on my data.

Comment: Another option: `transpose(combn(sort(unique(var)), 2, simplify=FALSE))`. I'm not adding it because I see y'all have discussed speed and I don't know it to be faster. Other speed considerations, maybe `unique(DT)[order(var), ...]` instead of sorting and uniquifying per `by=` group.

Comment: @Frank, in your edit to the answer, you use `transpose(combn(var, 2, simplify=FALSE))`, i.e. without `sort(unique(var))`. Is there a reason for that? I get slightly different results with that and I think the `sort(unique(..))` should be used, right?

Comment: @docendo I think the `unique` at the front should take care of duplicates. If you have other columns besides the two, then switch from `unique(DT, by=NULL)` to `unique(DT[, c("id","var"), with=FALSE], by=NULL)`. You shouldn't need to `sort` since there's the `order` call in `i` now.

Comment: @Frank, I agree that the `unique` is not necessary. However, I only get equal results to eddi's original approach when I include the `sort`. Thanks anyway